# sending a message to bot: v3 directline.postActivity vs. v4 dispatch from webchat store

Tags: botframework, web-chat

We are migrating from BotFramework-Webchat v3 to v4. Usually we send a message from the chat through the directline object created from v3 BotChat using the directline.postActivity function. However in our v4 implementation there were issues with the behavior of messages shown in the chat window when posting activities like this.

It seems that sending messages through the webchat redux store as shown in this [example](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/a.welcome-event) is the recommended approach.

I am wondering what is the difference between these two usages? It seems something is different between v3 and v4 versions and I am having difficulty finding references in the documentation about this. Should directline.postActivity be avoided completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't documented anywhere, but best practice *is* what is demonstrated via the [samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples), by use of the Web Chat redux store and its list of available [actions](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/packages/core/src/actions).

Essentially, Web Chat v4 is built on top of [BotFramework-DirectlineJS](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-DirectLineJS) which *does* use observables. Web Chat then translates the Direct Line observables into its own methods for consumption internally and by the user.

As you noted, it is possible to use the Direct Line observables in Web Chat but it is neither the best method nor the best practice to do so. Primarily, because Web Chat wasn't specifically designed around their use, except internally. It can work, but it opens you up to potentially curious behavior.

Comment: I see. I am using the es5 bundle actually, and based on the v4 samples, it seems none of them interface with the directline object directly. 

I'm not sure if my v3 approach was correct, but there were occurrences where the channel would be unresponsive. So our approach was to poll the bot with empty text activities, while listening for the watermark to be set as a signal to process further logic on the client side.

For v4, I want to show a welcome scenario, so I am following the sample by listening for 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED' and sending an welcome initiate event without polling.

Comment: My concern comes from whether this is a 'safe' method in ensuring a reliable connection.  I am just having trouble finding documentation/conversation that covers this kind of topic.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "is this a 'safe' method". Can you explain?

Comment: I'm sorry I think my confusion comes from not completely understanding how the Directline connection is established.

As to what I mean by 'safe', in v3 sometimes messages were dropped before watermark was set, so we postActivity with empty text and assumed that when the response from the bot returns with the watermark value set, then it is safe to interact with the bot. In v4 it seems that we can listen for 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED'  activity to be returned and assume that is safe to interact with the bot.

Comment: The `watermark` is used, primarily, for retrieving the conversation history by recalling the conversation at a certain activity (reference the [conversation history](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-DirectLineJS#resume-an-existing-conversation) doc). Indirectly, it can be used for tracking activities as they come in. Once Web Chat connects with Direct Line and messages are passed between Web Chat and your bot, it is then "safe". There is no need to wait for the `watermark` to be included.